# Compressing a discontinuous vector to continuous vector from 1 in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector:

```
4 8 10 12
```

I want to compress it to a vector starts from 1, like

```
1 2 3 4
```

How could I do that in R?

**Update:**

I have two vectors:

```
4 6 10 7
8 6 6 2
```

and want to convert them to:

```
2 3 6 4
5 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq_along`

```
v2 <- seq_along(v1)
```

If there are duplicate elements and wants those duplicates to have same number, use `match`

```
match(v1, unique(v1))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

or `factor`

```
as.integer(factor(v1, levels = unique(v1)))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

In case if the repeating elements are not adjacent and want to give them distinct values, use `rle`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(v1), values <- seq_along(values)))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

NOTE: Covered most of the cases as the post was not that clear.

#### Update

For the new vectors, we concatenate it together and do a `factor` or `match`

```
r1 <- match(vN, unique(sort(vN)))
r1
#[1] 2 3 6 4 5 3 3 1
split(r1, rep(1:2, lengths(list(v1N, v2N))))
#$`1`
#[1] 2 3 6 4

#$`2`
#[1] 5 3 3 1
```

### Data

```
v1 <- c(4, 8, 10, 12)
v1N <- c(4, 6, 10, 7)
v2N <- c(8, 6, 6, 2)
vN <- c(v1N, v2N)
```

Comment: Really thanks. I updated my question a little bit. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
x1 <- c(4, 6, 10, 7)
x2 <- c(8, 6, 6, 2)
m_factors <- matrix(as.numeric(as.factor(rbind(x1,x2))),nrow=2)
y1 <- m_factors[1,]
y2 <- m_factors[2,]
> y1
#[1] 2 3 6 4
> y2
#[1] 5 3 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case you can use `length` function

```
1:length(unique(v1))
```